# Error in counting character(s) entered by user using Java

Tags: java, count, character

I am supposed to create a program that counts the number of specific types of characters 
entered by the user. The number of upper case letters, lower case letters, digits 
(`0` through `9`) and other characters other than the `#` sign are counted. The user enters # to exit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class countchars
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    char sym;
    int up = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int other = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");
    sym = input.next().charAt(0);

    while(sym != '#')
    {
    System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");
    sym = input.next().charAt(0);

    if (sym >= 'a' && sym <= 'z')
        {
        low++;
        }   
    } 

    System.out.printf("Number of lowercase letters: %d\n", low);
    }
}
```

That's what I have so far for the lowercase count. The problem is when I run the program and enter 4 lowercase letters, it only counts 3.

Comment: you could try adding print statements inside your if statement together with your low++ to confirm how many times it entered the statement :)

Comment: Homework question? Should be tagged.

Comment: @EvanKnowles `Home Work` tag is OBSOLETE -> http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change like this

```
while(sym != '#')
    {

    if (sym >= 'a' && sym <= 'z')
        {
        low++;
        }

    System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");
    sym = input.next().charAt(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have called

```
input.next()
```

twice by the first time you count, so the first character is discarded, messing up your count by one.

Answer (score 0):

don't use two times input.next();

use this

```
sym = input.next().charAt(0);

    while(sym != '#')
    {
    System.out.print("Enter a character # to quit: ");
    //sym = input.next().charAt(0); removed this line and try

    if (sym >= 'a' && sym <= 'z')
        {
        low++;
        }


    }
```